# Query to return customer order history?

Tags: database, sql

I am trying to dump historical customer order data from a legacy ecommerce site that we restored from an AMI. Ideally this would grab customer ID, email, order date, product SKUs ordered, and order totals. Is this possible to do through a straight sql query or would we be better off fixing the broken PHP framework and exporting from Magento?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really depends on your version of Magento and whether there are flat sales tables or not.

If there are flat sales tables, then straight SQL is:

```
select e.*,sfoi.* from sales_flat_order e
left join sales_flat_order_item sfoi on (e.entity_id=sfoi.order_id)
where e.customer_email = '[your_customer_id]';
```

Via the object model:

```
$customer_email = 'youremail@gmail.com';
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email',array('like'=>$customer_email));

foreach($collection as $order){
    //do something
    echo $order->getCustomerEmail();
}
```

Comment: This is version 1.3.2.3, which unfortunately does not appear to have flat sales tables, looks like that is only for 1.5 and up.

Comment: For non-flat tables using SQL, you have to do EAV joins. This can get tricky, and is based on your install's EAV attribute Ids. I highly recommend *not* doing it this way because every column requires an explicit join.

Comment: Alright, thanks @philwinkle, back to fixing that PHP stuff.

Comment: @Alex I suggest setting up the DB against a vanilla 1.3.2.4 install and using the default theme. That will ensure you have a working application against which to run the collection-based query. Good luck!