# Magento 1.9: Get Product details for a Customer Order

Tags: magento-1.9, database, collection

I am trying to get the `product_id` of each `orders` that the `customer` has ordered.

One simple way is to fetch all the orders, and for each order have a loop to get all items for each order. Which will be too many database queries.

What I am trying to do is join `sales/order_collection` and `sales_flat_order_item` w.r.t the `order_id`, but the problem which is happening is, it is not able to join as in sales_flat_order_item there are columns with same `order_id`.

My code is as following :

```
 $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId());
 $orders->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            array('order_item' => 'sales_flat_order_item'),    // joined table alias
            "order_item.order_id=main_table.entity_id",      // join condition, main_table->predefined alias.
            array(order_item.product_id) // select
        );
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

You've got an issue with your query near `order_item.product_id`. I've fixed the issue and shared the answer below. Please give a try with it.

```
$customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();

$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.customer_id', $customerId);
$orders->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('order_item' => 'sales_flat_order_item'),    // joined table alias
        "order_item.order_id = main_table.entity_id",      // join condition, main_table->predefined alias.
        array('product_id') // select
    );
```

**Edit: Get order items (products) by Order number**

```
SELECT sales_flat_order.entity_id, sales_flat_order.increment_id, sales_flat_order_item.item_id, sales_flat_order_item.sku,  sales_flat_order_item.name from sales_flat_order right join sales_flat_order_item on sales_flat_order.entity_id = sales_flat_order_item.order_id where entity_id = 'order_id';
```

***Hope it helps!!!***

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I corrected it, but still it doesn't get the required `product_id` field. I don't know the reason why its failing. One reason I can think of is that there are mulitple `order_id` in `sales_flat_order_item`.

Comment: yes you're right, there are multiple order_id in sales_flat_order_item as one order may contain multiple items. You can try distinct or group by for this.

Comment: I tried with `group`, but somehow it doesn't help.

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3551/query-to-return-customer-order-history

Comment: Its a good approach, but it won't solve the problem of getting the product details for me.
Is there any way, I can just pass all the order_id I get from `sales/order_collection` like an array and get respective fields in `sales_flat_order_item`

Comment: Updated my answer with SQL query to get the ordered items with the order id.